# newer versions of Android are released are not compatible with new devices

Tags: android, performance

My application run succesfully on android version 2.3 and below but it gives response null in android 4.0 and 4.2.   After searching on google I came to know that HoneyComb and Ice Cream Sandwich are much stricter about abuse against the UI Thread.

> Some examples of other operations that ICS and HoneyComb won't allow you to perform on the UI thread are:

```
Opening a Socket connection (i.e. new Socket()).
HTTP requests (i.e. HTTPClient and HTTPUrlConnection).
Attempting to connect to a remote MySQL database.
Downloading a file (i.e. Downloader.downloadFile()).

If you are attempting to perform any of these operations on the UI thread, you must wrap them in a worker thread. The easiest way to do this is to use of an AsyncTask, which allows you to perform asynchronous work on your user interface. An AsyncTask will perform the blocking operations in a worker thread and will publish the results on the UI thread, without requiring you to handle threads and/or handlers yourself.
```

It means noe I have to change my old code? I had call HTTP requests in my project more than 50 times. So I have to change it manually in every class, so it will run on HTTP requests ?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You shouldnt be running network ops on the main thread anyway. so changing it would be a good thing.

Comment: You could create a class inheriting HTTPClient and HTTPUrlConnection, then override the functions you are using and wrap the calls to the super functions in an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

This is cause you have written network calls on main thread.. Just use [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead. It'll work flow less and it's also known as **Painless Threading** in Android, means that user don't need bother about Threads management.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you've to move all the Network related calls from your main thread. Easiest solution would be to create an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and call that at all the places where you've made your `HTTPRequest` calls. Let your `AsyncTask` do those in the background.